# xcode 5 corrupts settings bundle localization?

Tags: ios, xcode, settings, plist, bundle

I have an xcode 4.x project which has a localized settings bundle. Localization works

I open and compile it in xcode 5 and the localization still works.

I begin to edit settings bundle in xcode 5 and the localization fails. It means I have the same structure I need in settings bundle, but with incorrect titles.

Comment: Are any error messages generated?

Comment: No error messages. Localization file looks like a list of pairs key-value. So xcode 5 behave as this file doesn't exist or is empty.